# Making an executable program with a shell script..?

Tags: 16.04, execute-command

**I made two shell (.sh) script files, `audio.sh` and `video.sh` for my Pi CCTV project.**

And I combined those two scripts:

```
sh -x video.sh & sh -x audio.sh &
```

I put the command above into a shell file and finally made the `test.sh` file, which now lanuches the two shell files simultaneously.

However, I'm not satisfied that I should run the command: `sudo ./test.sh`. I would like to make an executable file (double-click and launch) which can launch `test.sh`.

There is a YouTube video demonstrating that it's possible to make an Apple script in Mac OS (linking the two files, compile and execute) and export it by an executable program (.app format). If the program is launched, the two shell scripts are launched together in two Terminal window(s), as you see in the video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkY4_qYWfqI

**Is it possible to do such a thing like that in Ubuntu 16.04?**

**Making a program that executes the two shell scripts simultaneously?**

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you really mean a launcher icon that does this, or another program that is also doing something else?

Comment: The thing I would like to do is just to double-click an icon and launch the script. (like in the YouTube video)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `.desktop` file will provide what you want.

Create the following file, with a filename like `ANYTHING.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Exec=gksudo /MAKE/THIS/THE/PATH/TO/test.sh
Path=/MAKE/THIS/THE/PATH/TO/THE/OTHER/FILES
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=Pi CCTV project
Categories=AudioVideo;
```

Save it wherever you want, e.g. in `~/Desktop`, and it will run when you click on it.

Alternatively, save it in `~/.local/share/applications` if you want it to appear in your menu.

This runs `test.sh` with `gksudo` instead of `sudo`, to give you a graphical password dialog.

In `test.sh` add a `wait` to the end as so:

```
sh -x video.sh & sh -x audio.sh & wait
```

This is needed so the window won't close until both programs are finished.

If you really want two windows, change `test.sh` to:

```
xterm -e sh -x video.sh & xterm -e sh -x audio.sh & wait
```

and change `Terminal=true` to `false` in the `.desktop` file.

Comment: What should I put in 'Path' in the Desktop Entry?

Comment: The directory video.sh and audio.sh are in.  Replacing `~` with '/home/'+ your username+`/`

Comment: How should I link multiple file directories in one line at PATH: ~~ ?

Comment: I meant if the directory it is in is  *for example* `~/project/`, call it `/home/`YOURUSERNAME`/project/`.  You might get away with leaving out the whole `Path=` line, especially if `video.sh` and `audio.sh` are in different directories.

Comment: Thanks so much! Now I have an app that can launch both audio.sh and video.sh.. However, whenever I open the file, gksudo askes me to enter my password.. Is there any ways to bypass it? If I do that, it would be really perfect!

Comment: If you *needed* to run them with `sudo`, then no.  Why did you need to?

Comment: I am just bothered that I have to enter password every time I launch the program. Do I have to use sudo, then?

Comment: It depends on what is in `video.sh` and `audio.sh`.  Do those programs work if you don't use `sudo`?

Comment: Oh.. They actually don't need sudo permission since they are in the home directory. I changed the Exec: part to `./test.sh` and it just work really fine without entering a password! Thanks so much! 

Comment: @FelixLee Of course, if you want to identify this by a particular icon, you add a like like this: `Icon=/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/scalable/categories/applications-multimedia-symbolic.svg` or the like. (Just put in the absolute path to your preferred icon.)

Comment: Is that how to apply an icon for my program file?

Comment: @FelixLee Yes, just include that line you your `*.desktop` file, and the menus, dock, etc., will show the icon you assign.